# Symfony - protect one ressource with password / authenticate user only with password

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, passwords

I would like to implement a "share option" in a Symfony 6 project. Users can share certain resources with other people. The other people do not need to have an account in the application. But the sharing should still be protected with a password.

Unfortunately I haven't found anything about how to implement it using Symfony's methods.

I already tried to write a custom authenticator and check the password there. As far as I could find out, Symfony always needs a user object. This is exactly what I don't want. The people with the link should be authenticated only by a password and so call a subpage.

On the subpage there are different files available for download and the option to upload files. The "authentication" would have to serve for several requests, because the user should not always enter the password.

Each subpage can have a different password, which can be assigned by the user of the application. The password is stored in the database in the table of the resource. I am using the new Symfony Security Bundle with Passports. There I have tried the following:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
{
    $password = $request->request->get("_password");
    $redirectPath = $request->getSession()->get("_security.upload.target_path");
    $pathItems = explode("/", $redirectPath);
    $hash = end($pathItems);

    $party = $this->em->getRepository(Party::class)->findOneBy(["slug" => $hash]);

    if (!$party) {
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('no party');
    }

    if (!$party->getPassword()) {
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException("password wrong.");
    }

    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge("guest_user"), new CustomCredentials(
            function ($credentials, UserInterface $user) use ($party) {
                return $credentials === $party->getPassword();
            }, $password
        )
    );
}
```

In my opinion, however, this approach is very unclean.

Each resource has a UUID in the URL, which I can use to determine the resource. I first try to extract this from the URL and search for it in the database. The URL looks like this:

```
/upload/party/6c74d175-46ff-4004-a3b2-f9aa95badadc
```

My security configuration looks like this. I think I have some error here. Through dd() I tried to find out if the authenticator is called; unfortunately it is not. Each time the main firewall is called.

```
security:
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

        guest_user:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\GuestUser

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER: ~
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        upload:
            pattern: ^/upload$
            provider: guest_user

            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\PasswordAuthenticator

            form_login:
                login_path: check_password
                check_path: check_password

        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login

            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

Has anyone had a challenge like this before?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please read [Are "Point me in the right direction" questions acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/are-point-me-in-the-right-direction-questions-acceptable). We have no idea what you know, what you tried or where, exactly, you're stuck. Writing a proper answer here would require us to write the whole thing (which we're not here to do). Please post your attempt, explain what you expect it to do and explain what actually happens and we can try and help with that.

Comment: **you could** somewhere store those passwords and relate them to the content to be accessed, on a non-authenticated page you make a form which just requires the password and based on that you return the content related to that password

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thanks for the tip. However, I described by "I already tried to write a customer authenticator..." what I already tried. And limited by "using Symfony's method", which is irrelevant for my scenario. I appreciate any hint, even if I already read something about this, as the reasoning may be different. I will try to describe my problem better in my next question.

Comment: @johnSmith I had already thought about that, but I don't know exactly how to store this information for further requests.

Comment: _"I will try to describe my problem better in my next question"_ - You should describe your problem better in _this_ question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thank you for your time. I have tried to better describe my question and my approach. Do you think it is ok like this?

Comment: What's your `access_control` configuration? `^/upload/party/` should work, but you might need to add `ROLE_USER` to the `NullUser`.

Comment: I manage my role permissions as annotations above the action methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `NullUser` class and set an object of this class in the custom authenticator

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class NullUser implements UserInterface
{
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
    }
}
```

Or use a [custom voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#creating-the-custom-voter) instead of authenticators

Comment: I will try that out directly. If that works, it's brilliant!

Comment: There's also a [`MemoryUserProvider`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#memory-user-provider) that you can use directly via configuration. However, both solutions will authenticate _all_ users with the same password. Is that what you want? Different resources don't have different passwords?

Comment: @Artem do you know how to include the user class in the security configuration? I updated my question. in the UserProvider "entity" I specified a property. In the NullUser (GuestUser for me) I have no properties.

Comment: @msg No, I don't want that. I have specified my question about this. The password of each resource is stored in the database and should be checked in the authenticator.

Comment: @HelloSebastian the user provider is not necessary, just remove `provider: guest_user` from the firewalls configuration

Comment: @HelloSebastian but it's necessary to return `SelfValidatingPassport` instead of `Passport` in `authenticate` method. 
`return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($userId, fn(string $userId) => new NullUser()));`

for `$userId` you can generate a random value